# show selected nodes in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want to show selected nodes and edges when mouse hovers on a node. For example, when mouse is on node 'b' only node 'e' and edge connecting 'b' and 'e' is highlighted. Similarly, when mouse is on 'a', only node 'b' and edge connecting 'a' and 'b' is highlighted. I have used `eles.difference()`
My jsfiddle is here. It is working for all neighbours, not selected neighbors. 
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbuser/2per58mc/38/)

Snippet is here.

```js
  var elesJson = {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: 'a'} },
      { data: { id: 'b'} },
      { data: { id: 'c'} },
      { data: { id: 'd'} },
      { data: { id: 'e'} }
    ],
  edges: [
      { data: { id: 'ae', source: 'a', target: 'e' } },
      { data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
      { data: { id: 'be', source: 'b', target: 'e' } },
      { data: { id: 'bc', source: 'b', target: 'c' } },
      { data: { id: 'ce', source: 'c', target: 'e' } },
      { data: { id: 'cd', source: 'c', target: 'd' } },
      { data: { id: 'de', source: 'd', target: 'e' } }
  ] 
};

var selectJsona={
 nodes: [
    { data: { id: 'a'} },
    { data: { id: 'b' } } ],
edges: [    { data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' } } ]};
var selectJsonb={
 nodes: [
    { data: { id: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'b' } } ],
edges: [    { data: { id: 'eb', source: 'e', target: 'b' } } ]};




var cy=cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node').css({'background-color': 'red','content': 'data(id)'})
.selector('edge').css({'line-color': 'grey' })
.selector('node.highlight').css({'border-color': '#FFF','border-width': '2px'})
.selector('node.semitransp').css({ 'opacity': '0.5' })
.selector('edge.highlight').css({ 'mid-target-arrow-color': '#FFF' })
.selector('edge.semitransp').css({ 'opacity': '0.2' }),

  elements: elesJson,
  layout: {    name: 'circle'},
});


cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function(e){
    var neigh = e.target;
  cy.elements().difference(neigh.outgoers().union(neigh.incomers())).not(neigh).addClass('semitransp');
    neigh.addClass('highlight').outgoers().addClass('highlight');
});
cy.on('mouseout', 'node', function(e){
    var neigh = e.target;
    cy.elements().removeClass('semitransp');
  neigh.removeClass('highlight').outgoers().union(neigh.incomers()).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
#cy {
  width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="jquery.qtip.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.5/cytoscape.js "></script>
 
 
 </head>
<body>
         <div id="cy"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you describe which are those "selected nodes" you want to highlight?

Comment: How do you select multiple nodes and edges? Do you use the view-utilities extension? Please share some more information about your code. (I can't open the jsFiddle in chrome and firefox). Also, please add your code as a snippet in all cases, links are not reliable and the snippet is. Thanks <3

Comment: "selected nodes" are defined in two json variable.

Comment: But why are the nodes in selectJsonA? Does this have a specific reason?

Comment: Yes, I just want to highlight only that node when mouse is on 'a'. I am getting variables like 'selectJsonA' from other programs.

Comment: This seems like a really bad practice, I would strongly recommend using classes or mappers in each nodes data for fast and easy access to these information

Comment: @StephanT. I agree with you but failed to implement it.